# How to use offline Jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to run Jquery without internet connection, and I have problem with the path to it. My project is in ASP.NET core.

When I entered code like this:`<script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>`
and I got this error in my browser console :

```
GET https://localhost:44374/myProject/jquery-3.4.1.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I inserted Jquery file right into my root directory and to several others, but that did not work.

So how do I prevent c# from thinking that *jquery-3.4.1.js* is an action inside my controller ? (I do not want to use absolute path)

Comment: well is the file at that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass root directory './' and certify that file has the same name.

```
<script src="./jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep, that worked for me. I just have to use ~ instead of "."

Comment: `./` does not mean "root directory". It means "relative to the current directory". Just a "/" means "root directory"